# Make DuckDuckGo look exactly like Google

Tags: duckduckgo

I prefer the Google UI in some ways but I'm using Duckduckgo (DDG) now. Is there a way to make DDG similar to the Google Search UI? I have 5 main UI issues detailed below, is there a way to fix them?

1. URL at the top of every search result, instead of bottom.
2. Grouped search results, from the same website.
3. Date modified for each link

[image: Google Search Results with annotations]

4. DDG is highlighting search result on hover. DDG
5. When DDG search results is not satisfying, is there a way to quickly switch to Google instead, without having to open a new tab and type the same query?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution for issue (4) and (5).

4. Disable result highlight on hover. ([Solved](https://openuserjs.org/scripts/andros705/Disable_duckduckgo.com_result_highlight/source))
5. Send search terms to google, useful when you realise DDG is giving subpar results. ([Solved - press "g" to go to google](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/369804-press-g-to-google-duckduckgo/code))

To use the userscripts (javascript code), you can install [Tampermonkey extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) first and add the code linked in (4) and (5) into it. The code will then run whenever you open duckduckgo. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851758/how-do-set-userscript-in-microsoft-edge) goes into the steps in more detail.

Comment: Sorry, but you are not clear about what to do with this code.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah i've updated the answer. Do let me know if it's clearer

Comment: While links might be helpful, please bear in mind that answers in this site should be self contained. Considering this please add a summary of the linked resources and whenever be possible include the most relevant parts. P.S. As is point requires it's own solutions that shows that question requires more focus.